# The main help page for badges should specify that a tag must be on 100+ questions to earn tag-specific badges for it

Tags: feature-request, badges, wording, tag-badges, help-text

The description for the requirements to get a tag-specific badge listed on the [/help/badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) page says (for a bronze badge, for instance):

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

This information is **incomplete**. For quite a while in the past, I hoped I would be able to get at least a bronze [[my-little-pony]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony) tag badge on Science Fiction & Fantasy, before realizing that the tag must also be on at least 100 questions:

> These badges are awarded for participating in non community-wiki questions with particular tags. If enough votes are earned in a tag **with 100+ total questions**, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

This info is reported ONLY on the pages for tag-specific badges (e.g.  [/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze)), accessible by clicking on "Bronze Badge" in the Tag Badges section of the /help/badges page).

For sake of clarity, could this other requirement be mentioned on the main /help/badges page too?